# Mobile only div class

Tags: css, mobile

We are looking for a way to create a div class to only appear on mobile, ie. when the resolution is below 1024x768. We currently use:

```
hide-below-768
```

for resolutions above 768.

Would anyone be able to advise on setting for below?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    /* add css here */
}
```

This allows you to apply different class behaviours, wrapping and sizing rules depending on the browser view port size.

But this won't be just for mobiles.  It's also works when reducing the width of the browser window on desktop browser.

It's part of a technique called responsive design.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp